# after popup submit request it should open parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From parent window i am opening one pop up window. After success of pop up screen control should go to parent window but when i am trying the code below, parent window is coming first and child window is coming behind that screen.

```
 function A(requestId) 
 { //strong text
   B();//it will open child window
   c(); //after this i am trying to open parent window by calling this method here.
 }
```

function B() {
                var childWindowId = "v";

```
            var flowExecutionUrl = '#{flowExecutionUrl}';
            var contentUrl = something;
            var parentCallbackFunction = null;
            var destroyOnClose = true;
            cwmManager.create(childWindowId, draggable, title, helpMenu, width, height, windowContentClass, windowTitleClass, windowTitleImageClass,
                                closeIcon, windowBorder, suppressScrolling, modal, callbackFunction, contentId, contentUrl,
                                parentCallbackFunction, destroyOnClose);
            cwmManager.open(childWindowId);
              return true;         
        }
```

please help me through this.

Comment: can you paste the code blocks that holds user-defined function B() AND C()?

Comment: Why don't you just close the child window?

Comment: if  i close the child window then it will not go to next parent page

Answer (score 0):

1. open the new window using width & height using following code from parent window :-

   ```
   function myFunction() {var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
   ```
2. after success the pass the data to parent window